# How to determine the precision of intermediate results in a calculation process?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, numerical-calculus, rounding-error, significant-figures

How many digits of precision should be retained in the calculation process if I want the result of a mathematical operation to have n digits of precision?

For example, if I want the result of `sqrt(sin(x))` to be 10 digits of precision, then what should be the precision of `sin(x)` in the calculation?

If the precision of intermediate results is dependent on the content of the calculation, how to analyze the precision of intermediate results in various calculation processes?